Using specific Django LTS version with cookiecutter-django
Currently, the Cookiecutter Django template uses Django 5.0, which is not a long-term support (LTS) release.
I couldn't find clear instructions in their documentation on how to specify a different Django version during installation.
I'd like to use Django 4.2 with cookiecutter-django since it has LTS support until 2026. How can I do this?

The template aims to use the most recent version of Django possible* and was updated to Django 5.0 fairly recently. I don't think any 5.0 only feature are used, so you should be able to just downgrade the Django version to 4.2 in the requirements file requirements/base.txt.
*It's not yet using 5.1, we need to update but it's often the case of waiting for the ecosystem of packages to catch up first.

Just downgrading to Django 4.2 in requirements.txt should work?

In requirements/base.txt to be precise. Will update the answer
